# How to remove the last character from string and add that removed character in front of string to display full string in reverse order?

Tags: javascript, string

const str = "Hello world";

str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);

output = "Hello worl";

How can i get that removed element to add my string like this.

ex : -  str = "dHello worl";

const str = "Hello world";

str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);

output = "Hello worl";

How can i get that removed element to add my string like this.

ex : -  str = "dHello worl";

I'm expecting the answer in reverse order =  str = " world Hello"

Comment: Do you want to reverse the word order or the string itself? If you want to reverse the string, use reverse, if you want to reverse word order, use split(" "), reverse resulting array and join it with space as a separator.

Comment: Reversing a string is not the result of repeatedly moving the last character to the front. And of course, reversing "Hello World" results in "dlroW olleH", not in "world Hello". The later would required splitting the string into parts (`String.split()` is the method you need) and concatenating the parts in a reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by concatenating the last character with the rest of the string:

```
const str = 'Hello world'
const lastChar = str[str.length - 1]
const result = lastChar + str.substring(0, str.length - 1)
```